# How to stop building When I use Dockerfile build image?

Tags: docker, cloud, containers, dockerfile

I write some shell codes in my Dockerfile below to check some directories in container, if it doesn't have those folders I want to stop building.So what should I write in the Dockerfile to stop it?

```
FROM XXX
...
RUN if [ -d "/app/bin" -a  -d "/app/lib" -a -d "/app/conf" -a -d "/app/resource" -a -d "/app/log" -a -f "/app/bin/start.sh" ]; then mkdir -p /app/control/bin;  else SOME_CODES_TO_STOP_BUILDING; fi
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any shell command that fails (returns an exit status other than 0) will stop the build.  Some examples:

```sh
# Probably the most idiomatic shell scripting: if the test
# returns false, then the "&&" won't run mkdir, and the whole
# command returns false
RUN test -d /app/bin -a ... \
 && mkdir /app/control/bin

# "test" and "[" are the same thing
RUN [ -d /app/bin -a ... ] \
 && mkdir /app/control/bin

# This first step will just blow up the build if it fails
RUN [ -d /app/bin -a ... ]
# Then do the on-success command
RUN mkdir /app/control/bin

# Your original suggestion
# /bin/false does nothing but returns 1
RUN if [ -d /app/bin -a ... ]; \
    then mkdir /app/control/bin; \
    else false; \
    fi
```

Comment: Thanks@David Maze. I agree with you. I just write `exit -1` in the `else` statement and get a same result and I think your method is more simplified. Thanks!

Comment: not the case, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55940444/docker-build-is-not-stopping-on-failed-run-command?noredirect=1#55940890

Comment: I've just gone through and manually tested this (with `FROM busybox` before and `RUN echo x` after) and all of these cases stop the build.

Comment: I ended up here trying to find a good way to test build changes and quit at a certain step and your answer helped me, `RUN false` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to check for those directories before building the image? I'd suggest creating a shell script and execute the docker build command only if the directories are present.

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Singh. I have to write the check logic in my java program but I didn't find the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) can return a suitable value because its `CreateContainerCmdIT`  and `startContainerCmd` API only return container ID and empty warnings.So I have to use the Dockerfile method.