# Docker build is not stopping on failed run command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have this in a Dockerfile

```
RUN eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and I see:

> The command '/bin/sh -c eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add
>   /root/.ssh/id_rsa' returned a non-zero code: 1

but the docker build continues until it reaches the ENTRYPOINT and then exits. How can I get the docker build process to stop if one of the RUN commands exits with non-zero?

Comment: You may need `set -o pipefail` https://vaneyckt.io/posts/safer_bash_scripts_with_set_euxo_pipefail/

Comment: Can you provide a larger fragment of the Dockerfile that demonstrates the situation (including any required setup and a following RUN line that actually happens)?  Given that error message I’d normally expect `docker build` to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Docker don't connect the different parts of your run command as an logical `AND`. It is more like a `OR`

Do this:

```
RUN eval `ssh-agent -s` 
RUN ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

**TL;DR:** 
A short example why:

This works until the end:

```
FROM alpine
RUN exit 0
RUN echo Hello
```

This stops by the first `RUN`:

```
FROM alpine
RUN exit 1
RUN echo Hello
```

This run until the end (like your example):

```
FROM alpine
RUN exit 0 && exit 1
RUN echo Hello
```

Comment: so is there a way to stop the build on a step explicitly?

Comment: Typically, you chain your commands in as little `RUN` commands as possible, i.e. `RUN cmd1 && cmd2 && ...`. When one of these fail, the whole `RUN` block fails.

Comment: @MrCholo
If a step fail your build will be aborted by this step (under the explained constrains)

Comment: @bellackn
I thought the same, but take a look at my short example. I tried it out. It is a lite bit confusing. (`&&` behave like `||`)

Comment: this runs until the end `RUN exit 0 && exit 1` because the `exit 1` call is never hit. This because `exit` will end processing.

Comment: @MrCholo You are right. Sorry for my mistake. 
But this not explain your Issue. May it will be helpful to see the whole Dockerfile und the whole build log.

Comment: yes, for your experiment, you can update it to use `false` and `true` which are bash commands